# Upgrading to Symfony 2.3 - Duplicate headers received from server

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.3

Trying to upgrade my Symfony project from 2.2 to 2.3
This also requires that I upgrade the following packages:

- JMS/SecurityExtraBundle from 1.4.* to 1.5.*
- JMS/DIExtraBundle from 1.3.* to 1.4.*
- FOS/UserBundle from 1.3.1 to 1.3.*
- FOS/FacebookBundle from 1.1.0 to 1.2.*

After running composer update and cache:clear successfully, the main page of the project loads normally, but on attempting to login via the normal login form I get the error:

Duplicate headers received from server
The response from the server contained duplicate headers. This problem is generally the result of a misconfigured website or proxy. Only the website or proxy administrator can fix this issue.
Error 350 (net::ERR_RESPONSE_HEADERS_MULTIPLE_LOCATION): Multiple distinct Location headers received. This is disallowed to protect against HTTP response splitting attacks.

I've attempted to look through the docs for changes, but have had no joy as yet.
I am still unsure what the error means is going wrong or how to begin trouble shooting and fixing it.

**update**
Near as I can tell my config.yml and security.yml are inline with the docs for the versions of the bundles above.  I have ditched my custom provider.  I am still getting the same error.  I'm including links to pastebins in the hopes that someone will spot something I missed.

- security.yml: http://pastebin.com/0DXraUeW
- config.yml: http://pastebin.com/N1BDL1Um

I'm still looking into how / where Symfony sets headers generally and specifically where the headers for login_check are being set.  Feedback welcome :)

Comment: Did you try starting with a fresh `security.yml` file?

Comment: I needs my security.yml, but the point was well taken, I'm going through the upgraded bundles docs and my config.yml and security.yml looking for subtle changes to default setup.  Think I've found it in changes to how FOSFacebook and FOSUser bundles want to be setup to work together.  Trying to sort that with my custom provider now - hopefully that will be the trick :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed a unique check_path be specified for each login type.

```
#security.yml
firewalls:
    main:
        form_login:
            ...
            check_path: /login_check
        fos_facebook:
            ...
            check_path: /loginFb
        bit_google:
            ...
            check_path: /loginGoogle
```

and add matching routes:

```
#routing.yml
_security_check:
    pattern:  /loginFb

_security_google:
    pattern:  /loginGoogle
```